How can I find (or choose) the direction of a vector relative to other object (such as a plane)?
I'm working on a problem that requires that you find the shortest distance from a point to a plane. I can solve the problem by projecting any vector that connects a point (outside the plane) to the plane - on the normal vector of the plane.
The equation of the plane is given by
$$
P = (4,2,3) +s(1,-1,1)+t(0,1,2)
$$
A point not on the plane is $Q=(1,2,3)$. A vector that connects Q to P can be found by selecting a point B on the plane, like so: $\bar{v} = B-Q = (4,2,3)-(1,2,3) = (3,0,0)$. The normal $\bar{n}_p = (-3,-2,1)$ is found by calculating the cross-product of the two direction-vectors of the plane and $\bar{w}$ can be found by $Proj_{\bar{n}_p$} \bar{v} =(27/14,\, 9/7,\, -1/14)$
I have illustrated the set-up below:

I have three questions about this:

Is it correct that we know that $\bar{v}$'s direction is towards the plane?

Is it correct to say that we do not know the direction of $\bar{n}_p$ relative to the plane? i.e is the direction of $\bar{n}_p$ towards Q or in the opposite direction?

How can I find, or force, $\bar{w}$ to "point" at the Plane?


Note: I'm not a math major so I would appreciate if I could get an answer that is on a reasonable basic level. Thanks!

Do you know about inner product space(IPS)? If $W$ is a finite-dimensional IPS(your plane) and $y$ is your given point, then there exists a unique $u \in W$ and $z \in W^\perp$ , such as $y = u + z$. We can also prove that the distance between $y$ and $u$ is the smallest.

Sorry, no I don't know it. I'm looking for something more basic probably. But thank you.



Is it correct that we know that $\bar{v}$'s direction is towards the plane?


Yes, this is because the starting point Q is outside the plane, and the endpoint B is on the plane by construction (i.e., your vector is defined as the difference $B-Q$ (towards), rather than $Q-B$ (away)).


Is it correct to say that we do not know the direction of $\bar{n}_p$ relative to the plane? i.e is the direction of $\bar{n}_p$ towards Q or in the opposite direction?


The orientation of $\bar{n}_p$ will depend on the order of the operands in the cross product (it will point the other way if you swap them). The direction follows the right hand rule, but that's hard to make use of if you're working with components. You can dot $\bar{n}_p$ with $\bar{v}$ to find out which way $\bar{n}_p$ is pointing to with respect to Q. If it's on the same side as Q, the dot product will be negative (simply because the two vectors make an angle > 90 deg).

In your specific example
$$\bar{n}_p \cdot \bar{v} = [-3, -2, 1]\cdot[3, 0, 0] = (-3)(3) + (-2)(0) + (1)(0) = -9$$
so the normal is on the same side as Q.
Note also that the cross product will in general not give you a unit normal (of length 1, a.k.a. normalized); some operations require a unit-lenght normal. To normalize it, divide each component by the current length of the $\bar{n}_p$ vector. Also, if $\bar{n}_p$ is not oriented the way you want, just flip it by multiplying with -1.


How can I find, or force, $\bar{w}$ to "point" at the Plane?


If this is a programming problem, or if you're using some software tools, then it looks like the projection procedure you're using ( $Proj_{\bar{n}_p$} \bar{v}$) retains the proper direction of the projected vector component of $\bar{v}$ regardless of which normal you've chosen. Just one thing: I'm assuming the -1/14 for the z component is a typo, as it should be -9/14?
But if you were to do it "manually", if you have a unit length normal $\hat{n}_p$, then the dot product $\hat{n}_p \cdot \bar{v}$ will give you the (signed) length $w$ of the projected component, and then you can recover $\bar{w}$ by just scaling the unit normal by $w$, via $\bar{w} = w \hat{n}$ (since the sign is "baked in" into $w$, the direction will flip as necessary).

